# Jenkins incremental build

Tags: ant, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins. How to do "incremental build" in Jenkins. I can't find any option in Jenkins for the same.
I want my Hudson build job to build only the components that are changed in SVN.

Answer (score 0):

If it is maven project, you can click the advanced button in build section and enable "Incremental build - only build changed modules"

Answer (score 0):

I also try do this job after the full compile, I find the takari plugin to meet it , but it fail. It always comile all the source code to the target. So i think this could be done by the diff between the newest one and the old one in some place. But not very well tools to find the class or file diff in this situation.